# angular js - missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i'm using angular js for creating the json, but when i tried to make a json as shown below

```
$scope.newcolumns =[{"File 1":"file1.png"},{"File 1":"file2.png"}]
```

i'm getting `missing : after property id`

my code is as given below

```
 $scope.newcolumns = [];
    angular.forEach( $scope.datas, function(data){
            $scope.newcolumns.push({data.id : data.value});
    });
```

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: What is the content of datas? And be careful withe the wording, your not creating json, but straight forward Javascript variables

Comment: Could you remove space from `File 1` and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this,

```
var obj={};
obj[data.id]= data.value;
$scope.newcolumns.push(obj);
```

`{data.id : data.value}` is not a valied syntax `data.id` should be some name to a property it cannot be a variable. If you need to have variable field names then you need to do like above.

Answer (score -1):

`angular.foreach(data, function (e) {
    $scope.phones.push({ "File1 ": e.File1, "File2": e.File2});
        });`
Sorry, I can only do this for you

Comment: Problem solved on top, answer not clear enough fix and I will remove downvote