# Syntax Error: missing: after property id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.messages.$add({
                    $scope.phone : {
                    username: $scope.username,
                    email: $scope.email,
                    dob: $scope.dob
                    }
                  });
```

I am inserting some data into Firebase database but getting missing property id. I looked at following question: [angular js - missing : after property id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295477/angular-js-missing-after-property-id)

But in my case phone needs to be key. So how do I make a object for my case?

Comment: You can't have `$scope.phone` as key name

Comment: @codename-: Yes, you can. But they probably don't want to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I mean that you can't have in way he write it. I your answer you put this as a string, not variable - there are two different things.

Comment: @codename-: That may be what you *meant*, but it's not what you *said*. :-) You can absolutely have the key `$scope.phone`. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a value as a property name in an object literal.

You would need to create the object first and use bracket syntax to set the property using the value:

```
var msg = {};
msg[$scope.phone] = {
  username: $scope.username,
  email: $scope.email,
  dob: $scope.dob
};
$scope.messages.$add(msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.phone` isn't a valid property name literal. You could use `"$scope.phone"`:

```
$scope.messages.$add({
    "$scope.phone" : {
        username: $scope.username,
        email: $scope.email,
        dob: $scope.dob
    }
});
```

...**but** it will create a property with that actual name, which probably isn't what you want. Looking at that literal, I can't quite figure out from the names what you actually want, I can't quite make `phone` work in relation to the other field names.

---

Re your comment:

> See this example: usersRef.set({ alanisawesome: { date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912", full_name: "Alan Turing" } Instead of alaniawesome I want to have phone as my key.

You can't do that in an object initializer, the property name part of the property initializers in it are always taken literally. You'll have to do it in two separate statements:

```
var obj = {};
obj[alanisawesome] = { date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912", full_name: "Alan Turing" };
usersRef.set(obj);
```

That works because in JavaScript, when accessing a property name *outside* of an object initializer, you can use either dot notation and a literal property name (`obj.foo`), or bracketed notation and a *string* property name (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression, including a variable reference.

Comment: See this example:
usersRef.set({
alanisawesome: {
date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
full_name: "Alan Turing"
}

Instead of alaniawesome I want to have phone as my key.

Comment: @rishiag: Ah, that's different. I've added to the answer.